# How to Query data where table1's zone_id ==table2's zone_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

table1 informtion

```
create_table :zones do |t|
  t.integer :Zone_id
  t.string :Zone_name

  t.timestamps
end
```

Table2 information.

```
create_table :networks do |t|
  t.integer :zone_id
  t.integer :network_id
  t.string :network_name
  t.integer :local_tb_id
  t.string :interconnect
  t.integer :interconnect_tb_id
  t.string :tonegroup

  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Why do you have `zone_id` in your `zones` table? Why are you not depending on that table's primary key?

Answer (score 0):

You should be depending on the primary key, typically called `id`, from the `zones` table, not `zone_id`. In your `Zone` model, you would therefore have this:

```
has_many :networks
```

For more information, please read the [Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: i already done this associations.what should i have to write in network_controller.rb so that  i get network row corresponding to zone_id.  example if zone.zone_id==network.zone_id

Answer (score 0):

```
zone = Zone.find(1)  # where id = 1
networks = zone.networks  # This will return all networks where network.zone_id = 1
```

You need to understand more about rails association. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Edit:

for all zones

```
@zones = Zone.joins(:networks).all
@zones.each do |zone|
  zone.networks # Here is the each zones network
end
```

Comment: it only fetch the record of network where zone_id==1.what about other network where zone_id more than 1 .how to fetch other networks?????